# Jmeter Specific Value Boundary Extraction

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I need to extract session state value from below mentioned URL

//prod-ivit-app-pre-prod.azurewebsites.net/signin-callback?code=94fbb3a4a51f7b0511dde4f77c0fe317ffe779f4f4204c37f7fdc1fc289d5fc4&scope=openid%20profile%20ivit-webapi%20offline_access&state=45e7d468c3714746a41a3cf508101ff6**&session_state**=o8Keu5m8eo2o7F32HIhmQWWP08fM2LUNoDnlt1wO4lE.fd1d10da1e560b35d66f47b39ec6ea9d

I have tried boundary value Extractor but there is no right boundary above URL. How can I Extract the value from `"session_state"`

---

*Screen Shot of Boundary Extractor:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add [Right Boundary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor), it will automatically get until end of line

> Right Boundary Right boundary of value to find  (Required) No

Keep value empty and it will work as you need

Comment: After adding like above mentioned I'm getting below error =

Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in query at index 312: https://prod-ivit-app-pre-prod.azurewebsites.net/signin-callback?code=8a1ee3b105381a380fa5e02414f514673e85580c98062e65ab2ba23aba43853c&scope=openid+profile+ivit-webapi+offline_access&state=723be60101aa4d3f91bf5a451011202c&session_state=TElXItoDvb6wurzNH3WPL5bYiGKKizzZMIERSSP5WpM.0663a41263966706fd21cfad1d5e395b
Server: Kestrel

Comment: @Subodhya this error irrelevant to my solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use Boundary Extractor for this particular use case, consider switching to [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) instead, the relevant regular expression would be as simple as:

```
session_state=(\w+)
```

[image]

where:

- `\w` - escape for `w` [meta character](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp) which matches alphanumeric strings including underscores
- `+` - stands for repetition

More information:

- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#regex)